# Iterating a list to get the three highest numbers of each group

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with US Census data. I am trying to display the three most populated counties per every state. I have been working for few days on the code but can't crack it. The only thing I need to work out is a way to iterate over all of the states to find the three highest numbers.

Here's my code so far:

```
cdf = census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
columns_to_keep = ['STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']
cdf = cdf[columns_to_keep].sort_values('CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False)
cdf = cdf[cdf['STNAME'].str.contains('Washington')][:3]
cdf
```

Here's a bit of current outcome:

```
        STNAME      CTYNAME     CENSUS2010POP
3017    Washington  King County 1931249
3027    Washington  Pierce County   795225
3031    Washington  Snohomish County    713335
```

Comment: kindly add a couple more rows for different states, with ur expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sort_values` with `groupby` + `head`

```
cdf= cdf.sort_values('CENSUS2010POP',ascending=False).groupby('STNAME').head(3)
```